# what is "count" doing in this code for censoring a word?

Tags: python, python-2.7, count

Okay, so I was over at Codecademy and I've been stuck on this code for a while, I just wasn't getting it. So I eventually ended up just getting the solution and trying to understand it. but I'm not really understanding it all.

The **code** is:

```
def censor(text, word):
  words = text.split()
  result = ''
  stars = '*' * len(word)
  count = 0
  for i in words:
    if i == word:
      words[count] = stars
      count += 1
  result =' '.join(words)

  return result

print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

Now I think count has to be the index (Since it says `words[count] = stars`), but I don't get why they set it to an integer (0) or added one to it, I'm guessing it has to do with setting the placement of the censoring in the text but would really appreciate if someone could explain this better to a newbie so I'm not just getting through this without understanding it.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think it's **count**ing something

Comment: That code doesn't even work right. It censors the first two words...

Comment: Its manually handling an [enumeration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) of the for loop.

Comment: If you copied the code correctly and the line `count += 1` is indented the same as the line before it, I don't see how this works correctly: the code will censor the first _n_ words instead of the matching words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you copied the code wrong mate. Here's what I think it should be -

```
def censor(text, word):
  words = text.split()
  result = ''
  stars = '*' * len(word)
  count = 0
  for i in words:
    if i == word:
      words[count] = stars
    count += 1  # this line executes regardless of the if condition
  result =' '.join(words)

  return result

print censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack")
```

Here `count` it keeping track of the position of the word under evaluation. If the word happens to be equal to the censored word, it correctly replaces the word with stars. Now how do you know where that word is in the list? - **count**

Comment: Ahhh, I think i get it now! it adds 1 to the count each time it iterates to new indice in the list ( The split string ) to keep track of what word should be replaced by the stars. (I should have figured this out, but didn't)

One more question if you don't mind, what part of the code is telling you to remove the word and -Replace- it? to me it looks like it would just add the stars to the string..

I was convinced i would have to use .remove() there somewhere, but obviously that wasn't right.. :/

Thanks for your answer mate! and you're right i messed up the code during formatting.

Comment: The line `words[count] = stars` **overwrites** the contents at the specified position. Thus effectively replacing the old word with stars

Answer (score 0):

One way to give you a better indication of what is going on is as follows;
Make **count** a global variable so you can access it outside the function, then simply print the result.

```
def censor(text, word):
  words = text.split()
  result = ''
  stars = '*' * len(word)
  global count
  count = 0
  for i in words:
    if i == word:
      words[count] = stars
      count += 1
  result =' '.join(words)

  return result

print(censor("this hack is wack hack", "hack"))
print(count)
```

When ran, you will see that **count** returns a value of **2**

Count is incremented by 1 when it encounters the word that is being censored.

However, as some of the other users have pointed out in the comments, the 'censoring' doesn't quite work!

Comment: .. or print it inside the function

Comment: Yea i messed up the code while formatting it here to post it.. Indented count under the if statement but it wasn't supposed to be there :/